# Can the bq tool use the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT env variable?

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

We use the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable to change projects.

This works well when using the Google Cloud libraries (for example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python).

But the `bq` command line tool doesn't seem to respect that environment variable. Is there a way of encouraging it to?

Already tried:

- Unsetting a default in `gcloud config`
- Adding `project_id=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` in `.bigqueryrc`

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you can run "gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT" before running bq commands.

Comment: You can also pass in `—project_id` as a flag, which should allow you to do `—project_id=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` when invoking the CLI. You could alias the bq command as `alias bq=bq —project_id=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` as well.

Comment: Good idea re the alias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bq` tool respects the Cloud SDK setting for project (as you mentioned in your original question).

That being said, the Cloud SDK has environment variables for all properties in the form of: `CLOUDSDK_<SECTION>_<PROPERTY>`.

So you can: `export CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`
if you want them to match.